# Min/max width is undefined for table rows

Tags: html, css, laravel, html-tabla, dompdf

tengo un problema a la hora de generar una tabla en html el error es este: "Min/max width is undefined for table rows" y la verdad no se que hacer, ya intente buscar una solucion pero por mas que solucion encuentro no me lo resuelve. comparto mi codigo.

Blade:

```
  <div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
  <table class="separado" align="text-justify" border="1">
    <thead>
      <tr>
                    <!-- <th scope="col">No. Solicitudes</th> -->
                    <th scope="col">Folio</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fecha de recibido</th>
                    <th scope="col">Fecha de solicitud</th>
                    <th scope="col">No. referencia</th>
                    <th scope="col">Remitente</th>
                    <th scope="col">No. telefonico</th>
                    <th scope="col">Observaciones</th>
                    <th scope="col">Tipo de solicitud</th>
                    <th scope="col">No. expendiente</th>
                    <th scope="col">Prioridad</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach ($report as $soli)
      <tr>
                    <!-- <td rowspan="3">{{$count}}</td> -->
                    <td>{{$soli->Folio}}</td>
                    <td>{{$soli->Fecha_recibido}}</td>
                    <td>{{$soli->created_at}}</td>
                    <td>{{$soli->Referencia}}</td>
                    <td>{{$soli->remitente}}</td>
                    <td>{{$soli->Telefono}}</td>
                    <td>{{$soli->Observaciones}}</td>
                    <td>{{$soli->fk_tipoSolicitud}}</td>
                    <td>{{$soli->Num_Expe}}</td>
                    <td>{{$soli->Prioridad}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Asunto</th>
                <td colspan="10">{{$soli->asunto}}</td>
            </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="2">Turnado a</th>
                        <td colspan="10">{{$soli->turnar}}</td>
                </tr>
                  @endforeach
        </tfoot>

  </table>
</div>
```

Función de mi controlador

```
     public function reporte(){
$dates = Carbon::now();
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'ES');
$dates = $dates->format('Y-m-d');

$sum = 0;
$count = $sum + $sum++;
// dd($count);

$reporte = DB::table('solicitudes')
->select('solicitudes.id','solicitudes.Folio','solicitudes.Num_Expe','solicitudes.Fecha_recibido','solicitudes.Telefono',
          'solicitudes.Referencia','solicitudes.Observaciones','solicitudes.turnar','solicitudes.Email','solicitudes.Prioridad',
          'solicitudes.asunto','solicitudes.remitente','solicitudes.fk_tipoSolicitud','solicitudes.created_at')
->whereDate('solicitudes.created_at','=','2022-09-13')
->get();
// dd($reporte);

$data = [
  'count' => $count,
  'report' => $reporte
];
$paper_orientation = 'landscape';
$customPaper = array(0,0,950,950);

// return PDF::loadView('administration\PDFs\Report_diario', $data)->setPaper($customPaper,$paper_orientation)
//           ->stream('Reporte diario de peticiones ciudadanas.pdf');
return PDF::loadView('administration\PDFs\Report_diario', $data)->setPaper('a4','landscape')
          ->stream('Reporte diario de peticiones ciudadanas.pdf');
   }
```

cuando genero mi reporte y solo me trae una sola consulta funciona y se muestra todo normal, pero si en mi consulta me trae 2 o mas ya no me funciona y me muestra ese error.

les agradecería que me guíen en que parte me equivoque o hice mal ya que es la primera vez que me sale ese error y no me había sucedido antes.

Comment: ¿podría ser que el error lo causara tener dentro del bucle estas etiquetas sin su pareja?  `</tbody><tfoot>`

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @masterguru ya identifique mi problema, si era en el bucle y en la etiqueta de </tfoot> tenia que haberlo colocado antes de cerrar el bucle y no después

Comment: Ojo con la otra: `</tbody>` pues la abres una sola vez antes del bucle y luego la cierras en cada ciclo del bucle, por lo tanto la cierras muchas veces

Comment: A entiendo checare eso, y tendré mas cuidado con mis etiquetas, ya que son muchos datos que debo tener en mi tabla no me alcanza el espacio de la hoja

Comment: Gracias el dato 